# Assign Selected Value in DropDown from Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list of page numbers that gets the correct values from a database query depending. Everything works correctly with this list except I can't seem to figure out how to retain the selected value in the dropdown. The page number is passed via a querystring and I'm retaining that as a ViewState variable. I can confirm that this variable is correctly retained by returning it the .aspx. How to I set that value as the selected though so the dropdown doesn't always revert to "1" when a new page is loaded?

My code behind:

```
public string proc;

public string page
{
    get { return ViewState["page"] as string; }
    set { ViewState["page"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    page = Request.QueryString["page"];
    Page_Numbers();
}

public void Page_Numbers()
{
    if (proc != null)
    {
        int totalRows;
        int totalPages;

        string sqlConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(sqlConn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = (proc);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        totalRows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        totalPages = ((totalRows / 1000) + 1);
        sqlConnection1.Close();

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
        {
            PageDdl.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));

            if (i == Convert.ToInt32(page))
            {
                PageDdl.SelectedItem.Value = page;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void PageDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("report.aspx?proc=" + proc + "&page=" + PageDdl.SelectedItem.Text);
}
```

My aspx:

```
        <div class="totalPages">   
            <asp:DropDownList ID="PageDdl" runat="server" 
                onselectedindexchanged="PageDdl_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                AutoPostBack="True" Visible="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        Page: <%=page %>
```

On my aspx, *page* variable is displayed so I can confirm it is assigned correctly.

Comment: Can you define "when a new page is loaded"? Do you mean they click a button on your page (PostBack) or they reload your page from scratch (e.g. pressing F5?)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the selected value with 1 line inside your for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
{
    PageDdl.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = i.ToString(), Selected = i == Convert.ToInt32(page) });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewState is cleared every time the page is loaded. To retain it even if the page is reloaded, store it in Session instead. Also, your Page_Load is going to overwrite it every time. So yes, you're storing it in ViewState, but maybe you want to check if it's in ViewState and not overwrite it?

Comment: Its not being overwritten each time so the ViewState is working correctly. The issue isn't that the variable is lost its that I'm trying to assign it as the selected value in the dropdown.